# Simple function formula

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

Let $f$ be a simple function in $(\mathbb{R},B(\mathbb{R}),\mu)$.

Can we write $f=\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_k.1_{[a_k,b_k]}$ instead of $f=\sum_{k=0}^n\alpha_k.1_{A_k}$ with $A_k\in B(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: Not in general. There are Borel sets which are not intervals. Take for instance the Cantor set (which is closed, hence Borel). How would you decompose it into closed intervals?

Comment: I see, but in the proof of Reimann Lebesgue Lemma. they choosed a simple function but they wrote it with intervals instead of just measurable sets

Comment: Functions of the form $f=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k 1_{[a_k,b_k]}$ are usually called *step* functions, as opposed to *simple* functions. Depending on the applications, it might be sufficient to consider only them.

Comment: So using the approximation theorm in $L^1$. there exists a step function $f_k$ such that the limit is $f\in L^1$. ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $A_0=\mathbb Z$. Then $f=1_{A_0}$ has no representation of the form $f=\sum_{k=0}^n c_k 1_{[a_k,b_k]}$.